# "pick on someone" ambiguity?

Tags: meaning

> The teacher tended to pick on her often because she came to class
> prepared.

Does it have two meanings?

a) The teacher harassed her.

b) picked her out, chose her

Answer (score 2):

In British English, 'pick on' does mean to *single someone out* for criticism or to receive other unkind behaviour. When we simply mean *to select* or *choose*, we just say 'pick', for example:

- The teacher picked me to read.
- The school bully picks on me.

Cambridge Dictionary tends to give the best British English steer, and no other meaning is listed for '[pick on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pick-on)' other than the one that suggests unkindness or harassment. Websters dictionary is predominantly a US English dictionary and it also only has the same single meaning for '[pick on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pick%20on)'.

The use of unnecessary prepositions is common, even among native speakers. For example, "*I don't want to miss out on the show*" could simply be "*I don't want to miss the show*". So your example isn't strictly *wrong* - it just has a preposition that isn't required, although in this specific example some could possibly perceive a different motive for the teacher.

Comment: This is what I found in a dictionary "to single out;
choose:" If I take the meaning you mention it means that the teacher criticized her. But is being prepared a reason for being critisized? It doesn't add up

Comment: https://www.wordreference.com/definition/pick%20on 15

Comment: @user1425 No, your dictionary broadly agrees with the two more scholarly dictionaries I linked to. "Pick on" does normally have a negative connotation related to bullying. If you read the last paragraph I have updated my answer with you'll see I think it is a 'mistake', although a fairly common one.

Comment: @user1425 In your example, it sounds like the teacher is *choosing* the student (to read, to comment) because they prepared. That doesn't sound like a bad thing at all, unless the wider context suggests that the teacher has a bad motive? I just think it's either an example of poor English or some colloquial, regional variation.

Comment: Maybe. I can only take your word for it. But here is another one: "The professor always picks on me to translate long passages." It's also from the dictionary. Random House Unabridged Dictionary of American English © 2022 Does it mean "he chooses me" or he is giving me a hard time asking to translate?

Comment: @user1425 As stated - and as supported by two scholarly dictionaries - "pick on" normally means *singled out* but for something unpleasant. If your examples are from native English speakers then it would seem that some people use it to just mean 'singled out', rightly or wrongly. By the way, the Random House dictionary **is** Websters which I linked to.

Comment: I made it clear that my examples are from Random House Unabridged Dictionary of American English © 2022

Comment: @user1425 I'll have to take your word for it because I don't have the printed edition, but the online edition of Websters (which Random House publish) doesn't have your example. To make sure I wasn't just speaking from a BrEng point of view, I consulted a friend from the USA today - he has lived in 3 different states and agrees with me. I just don't get why you'd ask a question and then argue with the answer. But looking at your history, you've asked 100s of questions and only accept answers on about 7% of them.

Comment: You are missing the point completely. I am not arguing with you. I just want to understand your reaction to the fact that the wrong examples are in dictionaries. See for yourself. https://www.wordreference.com/definition/pick%20on

Comment: @user1425 I don't have a 'reaction' - I have an instinct to rely on my 50 years as a native English speaker and scholarly resources such as the Cambridge and Websters dictionaries. I'm not swayed by your link to 'wordreference' which is the work of one man, Michael Kellogg, cribbing from other dictionaries.

Comment: I don't think that it matters that is who does the cribbing.